# Как исправить ошибку Unable to resolve the request: site/error на yii2 basic?

Tags: yii2, yii

Пишу сайт на `Yii2` basic. Осталась админка. Решил сделать ее отдельным модулем. Все работает, но возникает ошибка при попытке отправить форму. Содержание следующее:

> **yii\base\InvalidRouteException**: Unable to resolve the request:
>   site/error in
>   E:\servNew\OSPanel\domains\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php:128

Если кто-то знает пути решения, то буду благодарен.

Comment: а у вас роутинг для пост запроса есть для этой формы?

Comment: Добрый вечер. Без кода формы, конфигурации и структуры ничего нельзя определённо сказать. Дополните свой вопрос кодом.